# Backslash to forward in unicode string in Python

Tags: python, string, datetime, unicode

I have a spreadsheet with dates, usually encoded as strings in the format "DD\MM\YYYY", as 08\09\2014. The function I use returns the data as unicode, and I use Python 2.7. So, i start with:

```
> data_prob_raw
08\09\2014
```

To convert the string to a datetime object (datetime.parser.parse()) I need a string without '\', but I don't find a way to remove or substitute that problematic character with '/'.
I already tried with unicode codes:

```
data_prob_raw=data_prob_raw.replace(r'\x81', '/201')
data_prob_raw=data_prob_raw.replace(u'\x81', '/201')
```

And simply a string:

```
data_prob_raw=data_prob_raw.replace('\201','/201')
```

But it doesn't change anything:

```
08\09\2014
```

decoding the string:

```
data_prob_raw=data_raw_unic.encode('ascii')
```

But \201 goes uver the 128 ascii chars:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I solve that problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you read data into a file from python you should get an escaped string.

I have a file called `test.txt` with the contents `01\01\2010`

```
>>> with open(r'C:\users\john\desktop\test.txt') as f:
        s = f.read()

>>> s
'01\\01\\2010'
>>> s.replace('\\', '/')
'01/01/2010'
```

and I have no problem using `.replace` on the string. What might be happening is that you are creating a variable directly, to test the functionality, and are assigning `data_prob_raw='08\09\2014'` when you should be testing with either `data_prob_raw='08\\09\\2014'` or reading the date in from the file.

As zondo suggested you can also use raw stings like so; `data_prob_raw=r'08\09\2014'`. Notice the preceding `r`, that `r` tells Python to treat the backslashes as literal backslashes instead of parsing the escape characters.

Comment: The variable data_prob_raw is not created by me, but I searched so many solutions (creating directly the variable in Python shell too). Probably I get confused along. Simply, now it works! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To process simply a backslash in a string, you just have to put it twice. It is the escape character, so the following replace should be enough:

```
data_prob_raw=data_prob_raw.replace('\\', '/')
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to perform replacement.  `datetime` can parse any date format you specify:

```
>>> data = ur'08\09\2014'
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.strptime(data,ur'%m\%d\%Y')
datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 9, 0, 0)
```